# Nuxt options API with typescript no code completion

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

As mentioned in the title I am using Nuxtjs with typescript but there are no code completions in the template and script.

This is my code

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { FeaturedJobs } from '../../types/featuredJobs';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      transform: 0,
      movedTimes: 0,
      featuredJobs: {} as FeaturedJobs,
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.featuredJobs.title) // here i expect code completion to suggest title and othere properties (or anywhere else inside the template same situation)
  }

})
```

this is my nuxt config build modules where nuxt typescript build is added on installlation

```
buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
]
```

this is my package.json dev dependencies

```
 "devDependencies": {
   "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
   "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
   "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
   "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
   "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
 }
```

and this is tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

when I type `featuredJobs.` completions and suggestions does not come from FeaturedJobs type.

Comment: You may also need some VScode extensions + configuration if I remember correctly.

Comment: Do you know them? can you share please

Comment: I'm not into TS myself sorry. Did you checked [this module](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/)?

Comment: Yes I am using that module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my setup was ok and it works with the options API I just had to add the following line in my settings.json file after installing vetur, though this feature to work in experimental.

in settings.json:

```
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true
```